# How to change the Type icon of a particular content Type

Tags: content-type, file-icons

I'm creating some Content Types...

Is there any way to put inside the XML the information to describe the Icon of a Specific content type?

Something that overrides the document type or the folder icon..

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

In general most of the icons for document are defined in a file called docicon.xml you will find more on this in the following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms463701.aspx

Comment: But if I want to use it with Content Types, not looking at file extension or something else.. How could I do?

Answer (score 2):

Assigning Icons to the Features is quite possible but I don't think so you can do it for Content Types.

Comment: has this changed in SP 2013?

Comment: Sorry, you can't change it